# Insert random text into columns from a reference table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table ABSENCE that has 40 employee ids and need to add two columns from a table variable, which acts as a reference table. For each emp id, I need to randomly assign the values from the table variable. Here's the code I tried without randomizing:

```
USE TSQL2012;
GO
DECLARE @MAX SMALLINT;
DECLARE @MIN SMALLINT;
DECLARE @RECODE SMALLINT;
DECLARE @RE CHAR(100);

DECLARE @rearray table (recode smallint,re char(100));
insert into @rearray values (100,'HIT BY BEER TRUCK')
,(200,'BAD HAIR DAY')
,(300,'ASPIRIN OVERDOSE')
,(400,'MAKEUP DISASTER')
,(500,'GOT LOCKED IN THE SALOON')

DECLARE @REFCURSOR AS CURSOR;
SET @REFCURSOR = CURSOR FOR  
SELECT RECODE,RE FROM @REARRAY; 
OPEN @REFCURSOR; 

SET @MAX = (SELECT DISTINCT @@ROWCOUNT FROM ABSENCE); 
SET @MIN = 0; 
ALTER TABLE ABSENCE ADD CODE SMALLINT, REASONING CHAR(100);

WHILE (@MIN <= @MAX)
BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM @REFCURSOR INTO @RECODE,@RE; 
        INSERT INTO ABSENCE (CODE, REASONING) VALUES (@RECODE,@RE);
        SET @MIN+=1;
END
CLOSE @REFCURSOR
DEALLOCATE @REFCURSOR 

SELECT EMPID,CODE,REASONING FROM ABSENCE
```

Though am inserting into two columns only, it is attempting to insert into empid (which has already been filled) and as it cannot be NULL, the insertion fails.

Also, how to randomize the values from the REARRAY table variable to insert them into the ABSENCE table?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT @@ROWCOUNT`? What do you _think_ that means? Is it your intent to `UPDATE` the rows in `ABSENCE` to fill in values for the two new columns? `INSERT` needs to provide values for all columns, either explicitly or implicitly: identity columns, nullable columns and default values.

Comment: Wanted to obtain the # of rows through @@rowcount and loop. Thanks for the clarification about Insert though.

Comment: [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns the number of rows affected by the previous statement. Applying `DISTINCT` and using a `FROM` clause are baffling. You've written something rather like `declare @Pi as Float = ( select top 1 3.1415927 from Information_Schema.Table_Constraints where 42 is not NULL );`, though that would fail if the table has no rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a small dataset, one approach might be to use `CROSS APPLY` with a `SELECT TOP(1) ... FROM @rearray ORDER BY NEWID()` approach.  This will essentially join your `ABSENCE` table with your reference table in an `UPDATE` statement, selecting a random row each time in the join.  In full, it would look like:

```
UPDATE ABSENCE
SET col1 = x1.recode, col2 = x2.recode
FROM ABSENCE a
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM @rearray ORDER BY NEWID()) x1(recode, re)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM @rearray ORDER BY NEWID()) x2(recode, re)
```